# Is there a way to do simple "class-like" inheritance using objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I've run into a javascript question that I don't know how to resolve.  I'm grouping a bunch of variables and methods into a DocManager object.  Everything related to managing "documents" in my application lives here.  Basically, the DocManager acts like a class with a single instance.

Ex:

```
var DocManager = {
    doc_list : [],  //Array of documents containing content and metadata
    doc_index : 0,  //Index of the currently visible document
    loadDocList : function( collection_id, csrf_token, seq_list ){
      ...
    },
    showDocument : function(seq_index){
      ...,
    },
   ...
};
```

Now I've run into a situation where I'd like to subclass DocManager for use on different pages with different controls.  I need to add some methods and overwrite others.  Most of the functionality the object will stay the same.

What's the easiest way to do this?  I know javascript has a class/prototyping syntax for full-fledged object-orientation, and others have built OOP frameworks for js, but that seems like overkill for this situation.  I'd prefer to not learn a lot of new syntax to carry out this simple kind of object orientation.  What would you recommend?

Comment: Classical Inheritance in JavaScript - [info](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html)

Comment: I don't there is a workaround to the prototypical inheritance. May be this makes it easy for you. http://phrogz.net/js/classes/OOPinJS2.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply overwrite the functions you have assigned to it.

```
YourDocuManager.showDocument = function(index, newindex, whatever) {
....
}
```

from that moment it'll use the new function assigned.